# Stagger or Stair-Case a Menu

Tags: html, css, markup

I have a menu, created from the usual unordered list, that I want to style horizontally with CSS so that each menu entry is slightly lower than the prior entry.  The result would be a stair-case effect:

```
Home
      News
             About
                    Contact
```

My example above shows a full-line displacement for each menu entry, but what I actually want is pixel-level control of the stair-casing, so that each menu entry is potentially just a half or quarter character height displaced from the prior menu entry.

How do I make this trick work with CSS, preferably without uing CSS3? More precisely, isn't there a way to specify "this surface is to be rendered at position X,Y *relative* to the prior rendered item?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to manually add a `margin-top` to each `li`.

If you have a class on each `li`:

```
.first-li  { margin-top: 5px; }
.second-li { margin-top: 10px; }
/* ... */
```

If not, then:

```
#menu li:nth-child(1) { margin-top: 5px; }
#menu li:nth-child(2) { margin-top: 10px; }
/* ... */
```

Older browsers [don't support](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) `:nth-child`. There [is a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492121/ie8-nth-child-and-before/8492882#8492882) if you need to support older browsers and you don't want to add a class to each `li`.

Comment: I've updated my question, since I'm curious about a "relative placement" capability I thought was available in CSS.  I was certain, based on experience from my "prior life", that this could be done even without creating specific classes (e.g. '.first-li', '.second-li').

Comment: There's nothing like "relative to the previous (sibling) element". There is "relative to the parent element": http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: I think you are right.  If I'm going to get the effect I want, without CSS3 and without "one-css-class-per-menu", then perhaps I should use jquery to make an array of the nav elements and then attach the position:relative location for each entry in the array.